# RFID reader for unknown tag 125kHz

Tags: rfid

I have an unknown RFID tag and tried to read its value. I bought two readers, RDM6300 125KHZ and RC522 13.56MHz. Each of the readers connected to Arduino works well with the purchased corresponding tags, but not with this tag. According to my information, the tag should be 125kHz tag, but RDM6300 foes not read it. The tag is simply not detected. I am sure that the tag works, I use it to open the door.

So my question is: Is there any other RFID reader for Arduino, which is different than the two that I have, and could work?

Thank you.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 2):

It could be something else (in the RFID low freq ~ 125khz) like a HID card.
Also it could be an NFC (high freq 13.56Mhz) that its not compatible with the RC522.

Do you have access to a phone with NFC, to start ruling out what could it be?